# Class is inaccessible due to its protection level in DLL reference

Tags: c#, sql-server, powershell, xmla

I've seen this error in C# before when referencing a class with private properties, but I'm at a loss here, as this class has public properties. It's actually a microsoft .dll

I'm creating a new object:

`XmlaClient clnt = new XmlaClient();`

But that's where the "Class is inaccessible due to its protection level" error is coming from. I look at the class (dll) definition, and it shows all the items inside are public. Here's an excerpt:

using System.Data;

```
namespace Microsoft.AnalysisServices
{
    internal class XmlaClient
    {
        public XmlaClient();

        public ConnectionInfo ConnectionInfo { get; }
        public IdentityTransferToken IdentityTransferToken { get; set; }
        #etc etc
```

One thing I noticed is the namespace is different than my project's. My other .dll references have their own unique namespaces, so I didn't think that was the issue. Just a thought though.

Edit: Attempting to use Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.dll now. It seems quite a bit different than the previous DLL though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xmlaclient.Discover(MDSCHEMA\_MODULES,...) System out of memory exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241401/xmlaclient-discovermdschema-modules-system-out-of-memory-exception)

Comment: @Eris: Did you paste the wrong link?

Comment: While the topic of that question is different, the answer is still valid for this question.

Comment: @Eris: That's pretty far afield to make it a duplicate of this specific question.

Comment: @Eris I'm looking into the new DLL referenced there now to see if it will do what I need it to. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class itself is not public

```
internal class XmlaClient
^^^^^^^^
```